# Button to Display Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do some transitional text for my website, and I'm trying to have a button to click to transition some text.  I can do this with div tags, but with a specific element, I'm not able to.

So here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="infoLinks centerlinks">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 tips" id="hidetext">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Setup Info
      </button>
        <ul >
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/NETGEARSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your Netgear Wireless Router</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/DSLSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your DSL/CABLE Internet</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/VoIPSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your Internet with VoIP Phone</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#hidetext .showtext {
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  transition: color .75s ease-in;
}
#hidetext:hover .showtext{
  color: #000000;
}
```

Now when I change the button code to:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="hidetext">
   Setup Info
</button>
```

Now I imagine it's because my button isn't in the same element as my text.

How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: You can do that easyly using jQuery

Comment: for transition, use jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely CSS solution**. You can use a hidden `checkbox` to check for clicks. The `label` tag can be styled as a button. Clicking on which will actually check and uncheck the `checkbox`. Then with CSS `~` selector you can select the siblings and style them according to both checked and unchecked state.

```css
#clicker{
  display:none;
}
input#clicker ~ ul .showtext {
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: color .75s ease-in;
  transition: color .75s ease-in;
}
input#clicker:checked ~ ul .showtext {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="infoLinks centerlinks">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 tips">
      <input type="checkbox" id="clicker" />
      <label for="clicker" class="btn btn-primary" id="hidetext">
            Setup Info
      </label>
        <ul >
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/NETGEARSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your Netgear Wireless Router</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/DSLSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your DSL/CABLE Internet</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{var protoHost}}img/VoIPSetup.pdf" target="_blank" class="showtext">How to setup your Internet with VoIP Phone</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked!  Now I' m going to look up jquery and change it later.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you have written the css, the browser searchs for the element within the id `hidetext`. So if you remove the `hidetext` id, the code should work fine.